# optimizer.compute_gradients how the gradients are calculated programatically?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gradient

I'm new to machine learning.I was going through tensorflow and i have a doubt on a particular function.

grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss) can someone explain how the gradients are calculated programatically(i.e what formula does it use to compute the gradients)?

Comment: There is no formula because TF uses symbolic computations.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow uses an algorithm called reverse-mode automatic differentiation. It's too complex a topic to explain here, but the Wikipedia page is a good starting point:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation

Hope that helps!

Comment: Will do that. Thanks!